# Django - FormView combined with Mixin

Tags: django, django-forms, mixins, django-class-based-views

I have to specify a `success_url`, otherwise I get an error. So how to specify it, in order to stay to the same page?
Also, is everything else correct regarding the SearchView, beucase I have a feeling that something is missing. My context should be composed by `form`, `query`, `concepts`, `language` and `languages`.
Thanks

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<langcode>[a-zA-Z-]+)/search/$', SearchView.as_view(), name='search').
```

**views.py**

```
class _LanguageMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.langcode = kwargs.pop("langcode")
        self.language = get_object_or_404(Language, pk=self.langcode)
        return super(_LanguageMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(_LanguageMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({"language": self.language,
                        "languages": Language.objects.values_list('code',
                                                                  flat=True)})
        return context


class SearchView(_LanguageMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "search.html"
    form_class = SearchForm
    success_url = #......

    query = ''
    concepts = []

    def get_initial(self):
        return {'langcode': self.langcode}

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context.update({"query": self.query, "concepts": self.concepts})
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.query = form.cleaned_data['query']
        self.concepts = # here is a long DB query; function(query)

        return super(SearchView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**[EDIT]**
I did this:

```
def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('search', kwargs={'langcode': self.langcode})+"?query={}".format(self.query)
```

The form renders, but whenever I search for anything, I get back the empty search text field. And the URL looks something like this: `http://localhost:8000/en-US/search/?query=asd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a `FormView` (actually, any subclass of `ProcessFormView`) will return a `HttpResponseRedirect` in `form_valid`. As you are calling the `super`'s method in your `form_valid` method, you also return a `HttpResponseRedirect`. In the process, the actual `POST` data is lost, and though you pass it as a `GET` parameter, it is not used in the actual form.

To fix this, you need to not call `super` in your `form_valid` method, but instead return a rendered template in a `HttpResponse` object, e.g.:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.query = form.cleaned_data['query']
    self.concepts = # here is a long DB query; function(query)

    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Comment: I will try your solution when i'll be back to computer. Yet, why the POST data is getting lost? Because I am saving the context while procesing form_valid and the redirect inside super should know about this. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's a redirect on a HTTP level - you tell the client's browser to do a new request on the success url without the `POST` data. This is common practice with `POST` requests, as these requests generally change data in the database and should not be executed twice. By redirecting, a user cannot accidentally send the data twice to the server. In this case, however, you use the data to generate the response, so you shouldn't redirect the user. You might even want to use the `csrf_exempt` decorator on your `dispatch` method to allow cross-site requests.